# ImportError undefined symbol PyUnicodeUCS2_FromObject

Tags: c++, python, qt

Here is fragment of my c++ code (using Qt) in which I call a shell script of a python-application:

```
void MainWindow::CodeAsterError()
{
    ui->textBrowserError->append(caProcess->readAllStandardError());
}

void MainWindow::CodeAsterOut()
{
    QByteArray byteArray = caProcess->readAllStandardOutput();
    QStringList strLines = QString(byteArray).split("\n");

    foreach (QString line, strLines)
    {
        ui->textBrowserOut->append(line);
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString program = "/home/oogolov/aster/bin/as_run";
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "/home/oogolov/GeoFEA/GeoFEA2D/WorkDir/Calc.export";

    connect (caProcess, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(CodeAsterOut()));
    connect (caProcess, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()), this, SLOT(CodeAsterError()));

    caProcess->start(program,arguments);
    // works too
    //caProcess->start("/bin/bash", QStringList() << "/home/oogolov/aster/bin/as_run" << "/home/oogolov/GeoFEA/GeoFEA2D/WorkDir/Calc.export");
    caProcess->waitForReadyRead(100);
}
```

When I run (Build/Run) my application it works well. But when I debug (Debug/Start Debugging) I get following error:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

File "/home/oogolov/aster/lib/python2.7/site-packages/asrun/main.py", line 109, in main start()

File "/home/oogolov/aster/lib/python2.7/site-packages/asrun/main.py", line 51, in start run = AsterRun()

File "/home/oogolov/aster/lib/python2.7/site-packages/asrun/run.py", line 186, in __init__ self.LoadExtensions()

File "/home/oogolov/aster/lib/python2.7/site-packages/asrun/run.py", line 297, in LoadExtensions import asrun.maintenance

File "/home/oogolov/aster/lib/python2.7/site-packages/asrun/maintenance.py", line 42, in <module> from asrun.build import AsterBuild

File "/home/oogolov/aster/lib/python2.7/site-packages/asrun/build.py", line 31, in <module> from zipfile import ZipFile

File "/opt/QtSDK/debugger/Desktop/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 6, in <module> import io

File "/opt/QtSDK/debugger/Desktop/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 60, in <module> import _io

ImportError: /opt/QtSDK/debugger/Desktop/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_FromObject
```

---

Could you help me to repair this "Import, PyUnicodeUCS2_FromObject" state?

Answer (score 2):

Look here in the [semi-official Python FAQ](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/when-importing-module-x-why-do-i-get-undefined-symbol-pyunicodeucs2.htm).

It seems that the Python build you are using for debugging is not the same one you are using for running.